# Create a static library with React dependency

Tags: swift, xcode, reactjs, react-native, static-libraries

I created a library that uses the native navigation controller to navigate through react and native screens. The library is written in Swift and contains some objective-c code to setup the React bridge etc. Currently I can distribute this library through CocoaPods by creating a podspec and defining the React dependency there. However, this forces the user to setup React in their project through CocoaPods as well (like so: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps.html). I'd like them to use the `react-native link` or manually linking option as well (like so: https://medium.com/@joshyhargreaves/adding-react-native-to-existing-ios-project-without-cocoapods-6f1ee9106009).

If I understand correctly I can create a static library and distribute that. So far I created this static library, added my mixed swift and objective-c code and tried to manually link it into my main project. This however produces an error in one of my classes inside my static library where I import React like so `import React`. Error is `"No such module 'React'`.

I updated the Header Search Paths of my static library to contain:

`$(SRCROOT)/../react-native/React`
and
`$(SRCROOT)/../React`

(react-native, React and my own lib are all inside the node_modules folder)

both set to recursive. Unfortunately it still doesn't find the module React. Does anyone know how to create a static library that contains a dependency with React?

The end goal would be to import this static library in my main project like `import MyStaticNaivationLib` in one of my viewcontrollers and subclass from a class that's defined in my static library.

My main project also uses https://github.com/rebeccahughes/react-native-device-info. This looks exactly what I want to achieve. It's a static library that has a dependency with React ("import RCTBridgeModule.h") which I can manually link in my main project. Only difference is that this project doesn't contain Swift code.

Comment: did you find any work around??

Comment: @YashwanthReddy Unfortunately no. Still struggling with errors in the bridging header. Probably related to Swift.

Comment: Have you got any success? Actually I am also trying to convert my existing react native app to Lib?

Comment: Unfortunately no. Decided to drop react support and went full native. Sorry.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a custom module for the company, and you can view my documentation. This custom module have inner framework and I link this framework to the main project. In your custom_modulem do you have package.json with this?

```
 "peerDependencies": {
    "react": "16.8.3",
    "react-native": "0.59.4"
  }
```

https://github.com/Hardy1207/RNOkay